# Rails Pundit how the policies are worknig?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I have a web application in ruby on rails with devise as the authentication and pundit as the authorization.

I have a model `user` with an integer `role` attribute with values 0, 1, 2, for `visitor`, `vip`, and `admin` respectively. I also have a scaffold, say `Page` that I want just `vip` and `admin` to have access to and not `visitor` users.

In page_policy.rb I have

```
def index?
  current_user.vip? or current_user.admin?
end
```

and in pages_controller.rb I have a line `authorize current_user`.
Although I have given access to `vip` but it is available just for `admin` user. Where have I been wrong with the code?

Thank you

Comment: is `current_user.vip?` returning true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have properly set up your predicate methods `vip?` and `admin?` on the `User` model, and these work as expected? Can you check the result of calling each of these methods on your current user?

Pundit actually passes the result of `current_user` to your policy initializer, and you can access that via the `user` method inside your policy methods. Also I would be careful of using the `or` operator in this context (see http://www.virtuouscode.com/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

So I would try:

```
def index?
  user.vip? || user.admin?
end
```

Also, pundit expects you to pass the *resource* you are checking to the `authorize` method, not the user object. If you don't have an instance to pass, you can pass the class:

`authorize Page`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, it was due to the <code>authorize Page</code>.